# Почему работают только первые стили?

Tags: html, css

https://codepen.io/geharka/pen/GRxQKyK

Если комментировать стили, которые находятся вверху, те что внизу, начинают работать. Почему так?
Мне нужно чтоб всё работало.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="workSpace">
            <a href="#">WorkSpace</a>
        </div>
        <div class="settings">
            <a href="#">Settings</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

```
/* *{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}; */
nav{
    height: 10vh;
    background: #000;
    width: 100%;
};
.logo{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

точки с запятой лишние `;`

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  height: 40vh;
  background: #000;
  width: 100%;
}

logo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="workSpace">
    <a href="#">WorkSpace</a>
  </div>
  <div class="settings">
    <a href="#">Settings</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```